# QB SDK Error 3210 on Credit Card Year in Customer Insert

Tags: qbxml

I'm inserting a customer with credit card info (masked, but a test # in this example) and keep getting a 3210 error on the year. I've tried 2016 and 16, and both give the same results. What am I missing?

Here's the CC part of the insert request:

```
<CreditCardInfo>
<CreditCardNumber>4111111111111111</CreditCardNumber> 
<ExpirationMonth>9</ExpirationMonth> 
<ExpirationYear>2016</ExpirationYear> 
<NameOnCard>ben test</NameOnCard> 
</CreditCardInfo>
```

And the response:

```
<CustomerAddRs requestID="0" statusCode="3210" statusSeverity="Error" statusMessage="The "customer credit card expiration year" field has an invalid value "2016". QuickBooks error message: Invalid date." /> 
</QBXMLMsgsRs>
```

Comment: Which version of the SDK and which version of QuickBooks are you using? I tested with version 13 of the SDK and QuickBooks 14.0 R5. Both 2016 and 16 worked for me. Also, does the entire request validate using the XML Validator Tool?

Comment: SDK v12 and QB Enterprise 13 R12. The validator likes the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, check your QBXML version in the XML

Comment: <?qbxml version="13.0"?>